# How can I have the html root reference the application root (IIS)?

Tags: .net, iis

I have a .NET webforms application where an instance is normally deployed in IIS 7 with a host name as follows: "[appname].example.com". I now have a need to deploy them like this: "trial.example.com/[appname]/".

When I do this, the problem is that there are many url references to the root directory in the application e.g <img href="/images/logo.png"/> which of course point to "trial.example.com/images/logo.png" instead of where I need it to point: "trial.example.com/[appname]/images/logo.png".

Are there any possible solutions to this problem without having to change all the URLs to relative paths, or is that the only way?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Bad example on my part. I was hoping not to have to have to change the urls in the application as there many, and it would be quite an undertaking to change them all. Is there a way to do this with URL rewrites possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, by creating an outbound URL rewrite rule in IIS 7.
I ticked all the options for "Match the content within:" except "use custom tags"

The regular expression to match was: `(?!^\/appname)(^\/.*)`

This matches any path starting with / but not starting with /appname

The rewrite value was: `/appname{R:0}`

This adds /appname in front of whatever the original value was.

The rewrite rule appears in the Web.config as follow:

```
<outboundRules>
      <rule name="add app root">
            <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Head, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="(?!^\/testapp)(^\/.*)" negate="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="/testapp{R:0}" />
      </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
<img href="/images/logo.png"/>
```

use

```
<img src="~/images/logo.png" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I was aware of this, however in the .net documentation it says "The ~ operator is recognized only for server controls and in server code. You cannot use the ~ operator for client elements." When I tested the code on my local machine it didn't work with client elements. It did work when tested on the production environment, but I do need it to work locally too for testing purposes.